# Bower - PHP - Heroku

Tags: php, node.js, heroku, bower, buildpack

I am trying to deploy a PHP app on heroku and also have bower.
The problem is that, although heroku detects both node.js and php buildpacks, it doesn't run `bower install`.

I have found:

this: https://github.com/dzuelke/heroku-multipack-nodejs-php-example/blob/master/.buildpacks

and this: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi

but somehow I cannot get it to work.

Can anyone explain the **full process**?

### ---------------------------------------

Output of `heroku buildpacks`:

```
=== athens-night Buildpack URLs
1. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs
2. heroku/php
```

### ---------------------------------------

Some of my files, just for clarity:

### composer.json

```
{
  "name": "antony/athens-night-backend",
  "description": "Backend for Athen's Night Startup",
  "license": "MIT",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Antony Kalogeropoulos",
      "email": "anthonykalogeropoulos@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.0.0",
    "twig/twig": "~1.0",
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "^5.4",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.3",
    "ccampbell/chromephp": "^4.1"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "heroku/heroku-buildpack-php": "*"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Night\\": "app/"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "compile": [
        "bower install"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### Procfile

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

### bower.json

```
{
  "name": "athens-night-backend",
  "homepage": "http://athens-night.gr/",
  "authors": [
    "Antony Kalogeropoulos <anthonykalogeropoulos@gmail.com>"
  ],
  "description": "athens nightlife events",
  "main": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "gentelella": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

### .bowerrc

```
{
  "directory": "public/assets/"
}
```

### .buildpacks

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php
```

### .package.json

```
{
  "name": "multitest",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bower": "~1.3.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "4.0.0"
  }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I managed to `bower install` by changing the `package.json` to this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.5.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "4.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower cache clean && bower install"
  }
}
```

However I'm keeping this question open until I receive a well-explained answer about the full process of using bower with php on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `post-install-cmd` and `post-update-cmd` into `composer.json` scripts.

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "bower install"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "bower install"
    ]
  }
```

given that Heroku detects nodejs.

Here, Heroku will first detect nodejs, and going through `package.json`, it'll install `bower`. 
Then, `composer install` will run, finally installing bower components.

Comment: The `"scripts": {
      "compile": [
        "bower install"
      ]
    }` in composer.json doesn't help? Also, take a look at my update on the post.

Comment: @padawanTony That didn't work for me. Doesn't the above work for you?

Comment: No it's not working. the only thing working is the one I have on the update of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use nodejs buildpack. In heroku CLI:
`heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs`

You can check your used buildpack with `heroku buildpacks`